# How to get error message of Passport.js authentication strategy?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Authenticate method of passport.js is using specified authentication strategy to authenticate.

It should be as simple as in the example from [documentation](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/):

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  function(req, res) {
    // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
    // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
    res.redirect('/users/' + req.user.username);
  });
```

in particular I'm trying to employ [wsfed-saml2 strategy](https://github.com/auth0/passport-wsfed-saml2) to connect with ADFS server:

```
router.post('callbackPath',
    passport.authenticate('wsfed-saml2', {
      failureFlash: true,
      failureRedirect: 'somePath' 
    }),
  function onSuccessfulAuthentication(req, res, next) {
    res.redirect('/')
  })
```

In my case strategy fails to authorize successfully. However server is sending XML with data of the authenticated user properly. It seems that strategy is somehow unable to parse it.

Is there any way to get detailed error message from executed strategy? At this moment the only thing which happens is error redirection.

With slightly different configuration I've got following stack trace:

```
TypeError: req.flash is not a function
    at allFailed (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webapi\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:131:15)
    at attempt (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webapi\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:180:28)
    at WsFedSaml2Strategy.strategy.fail (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webapi\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:297:9)
    at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webapi\node_modules\passport-wsfed-saml2\lib\passport-wsfed-saml2\strategy.js:225:32
    at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webapi\node_modules\passport-wsfed-saml2\lib\passport-wsfed-saml2\samlp.js:363:20
    at Samlp.ignoreValidationFunction (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webapi\node_modules\passport-wsfed-saml2\lib\passport-wsfed-saml2\samlp.js:30:10)
    at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webapi\node_modules\passport-wsfed-saml2\lib\passport-wsfed-saml2\samlp.js:343:12
    at Samlp.ignoreValidationFunction (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webapi\node_modules\passport-wsfed-saml2\lib\passport-wsfed-saml2\samlp.js:30:10)
    at Samlp.validateSamlResponse (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webapi\node_modules\passport-wsfed-saml2\lib\passport-wsfed-saml2\samlp.js:338:10)
    at loaded (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webapi\node_modules\passport-wsfed-saml2\lib\passport-wsfed-saml2\strategy.js:224:21)
    at NullStore.verify (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webapi\node_modules\passport-wsfed-saml2\lib\passport-wsfed-saml2\state\null.js:9:3)
    at verifyState (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webapi\node_modules\passport-wsfed-saml2\lib\passport-wsfed-saml2\strategy.js:158:26)
    at executeSamlp (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webapi\node_modules\passport-wsfed-saml2\lib\passport-wsfed-saml2\strategy.js:244:7)
    at WsFedSaml2Strategy.authenticate (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webapi\node_modules\passport-wsfed-saml2\lib\passport-wsfed-saml2\strategy.js:289:5)
    at attempt (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webapi\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:361:16)
    at authenticate (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webapi\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:362:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webapi\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webapi\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webapi\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webapi\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webapi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webapi\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
```

But it also doesn't say what exactly is wrong with response. It just indicates that the response is somehow unacceptable for the wsfed-saml2 strategy.

How can I get more detailed error message when passport's strategy fail?

Comment: You can put console.log inside the code of passport and strategy you are using by going in your node_modules. This way you are able to get more details about the error.

Comment: Well finally this is something I did - modifying the source code of the strategy. But let's be honest - it shouldn't be the solution. Anyway thanks for the advice.

Comment: Good to know that your problem resolved. I understand this is not the best solution, Actually the error handling and logging inside the passport-jwt modules should be improved , That way we can get better picture of root cause. That's the reason havn't posted it as answer :)